# How do I use the different Google Maps APIs?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api

I want to use Google maps API. I looked at: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/ and I saw that there are different APIs:

1. The Google Places API
2. The Google Places-Autocomplete API
3. The Google Maps JavaScript API v3, and more

Can I use all of them in Eclipse with JavaScript? Or only the Google Maps JavaScript API v3?
Does the Google Maps JavaScript API v3 include the the Google Places API and the Google Places-Autocomplete API?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should definitely use v3 - the others are deprecated and at some point will not be supported and may not even be available.

From https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places:

> The Places service is contained within a self-contained library,
>   separate from the main Maps API JavaScript code.

You just need to include another script reference to get the additional Places library, and it includes Places Autocomplete.

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&sensor=true_or_false"></script>
```